# How to retrieve user specified heading data in pdf using java

Tags: pdf

Hi i've a requirement to retrieve user specified heading summary(all data of heading) in a pdf.
Thank Q

Comment: What is your definition of *user specified heading summary* (all data of heading). Explain it from the point of view of a computer, not a human being. A human being can use his intelligence to determine what a heading is based on visual aspects. A computer can't, so you'll need a better definition.

Comment: What's a heading? --- Unless you use specially crafted files, PDFs only contain information like "go to position x,y", "chose rotation, skewing, stretching", "select font", "draw glyphs", "draw lines", etc. Thus, to retrieve information from the PDF pages, you need to know very well what you are looking for. Or do you by heading mean PDF document properties or metadata or something similar?